# Inelastic momentum question: How to calculate velocity before the collision?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, collision

**EDIT: NEVERMIND! MY APOLOGIES, I DID NOT READ THE QUESTION PROPERLY. I DID NOT SEE THAT IT SAID THAT THE GUY WAS STATIONARY.**

I was doing a practice physics question and stumbled upon a question where it asked a question that goes like this:

[image]

I tried to solve it like this:

m1 = girl v1 = girl
m2 = boy v2 = boy

Therefore I got an equation:

m1v1 + m2v2 = m1&2 x v1&2

I solved for V2 (on the left hand side as the question asked for the girl's velocity before the collision). But the problem was that the question did not give me the velocity of the guy which got me stuck.

I tried to look into it in an energy perspective e.g. using kinetic energy equation to solve for v but no luck. Could someone give me an advice to solve this question?

Note: Please don't give me the answer because I wanna solve it myself using your guys' advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking about what the initial velocity of the boyfriend is? If so, it is 0, as the question tells you he is initially stationary.

However, regarding using energy to solve the problem: you stated that the collision is inelastic. What does this mean? Is energy conserved? If you think about the energy in inelastic collisions, I think you'll figure it out yourself :). If you're still stuck, I'll write the answer below.

Since the collision is inelastic, energy isn't conserved (some energy is lost to heat, sound, shape changes, etc.). Therefore, you can't use conservation of energy to solve this problem (since the initial energy doesn't equal the final energy). Momentum is the way to go.

Let me know if you want me to elaborate. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you F16Falcon! Yep, I just found out earlier that the question said that the boyfriend's velocity is stationary. Hence I edited my question as soon as I realized. In terms of energy in regards to inelastic momentum, I've learned that KE is not conserved because it is lost in some way which could be due to the change of the objects' shape. And I guess I would think of this as the energy changing in another form to say like heat energy (happens when a moving object loses its energy due to friction).  Once again, thank you and apologies because I did not comprehend the question properly.